# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy Exception on ClaimType

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm fairly new to Custom Policies in general, and would appreciate some guidance so that I'm not just testing random things and hoping something works.

I have the below Claims Provider set up in my policy:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-ReadCommon">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_PhoneNumber" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-WriteCommon">
      <!-- Transform optional claims (given name, surname) to proper display name -->
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_PhoneNumber" />
      </PersistedClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Note that the `CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName` transformation is a custom transformation I created:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" TransformationMethod="FormatStringMultipleClaims">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0} {1}" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

I'm getting the following error, specifically on expired password, inside the Technical Profile `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin`:

> A Claim of ClaimType with id "givenName" was not found, which is required by the ClaimsTransformationImpl of Type "Microsoft.Cpim.Data.Transformations.FormatStringMultipleClaimsTransformation" for TransformationMethod "FormatStringMultipleClaims" referenced by the ClaimsTransformation with id "CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName"```

Digging a bit further, I see that `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin` has `<IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-WriteCommon" />` listed in it, which I think explains what is happening - essentially, the chain of events dies on my custom transformation, because it is asking for two claims (`givenName` and `surname`), which the technical profile `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin` does not provide.

I tried a few attempts at getting it to work, by adding those two fields as input claims to `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin`, or to `SelfAsserted-ForcePasswordReset-ExpiredPassword`, which is the profile that is actually invoking it, but neither seemed to work.

Note that I'm not actually trying to change the experience for the end-user at all. On the screen where they are entering their password to update, there are no prompts asking for their name, nor is there any place where the name is actually intended to be displayed. If the solution involves making the `CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName` transformation somehow validate and skip the process if the information isn't available, I'm perfectly happy with that solution as well.

If there's any other information I can provide to help, please let me know. Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**
Okay, so I've done some more exploring, and I think I have a better understanding of where everything is.

My RP has this, from which I'm fairly sure the journey involved in this case would be `IdentityProviderSelection_SignUpSignIn`:

```
  <SubJourneys>
    <SubJourney Id="IdentityProviderSelection_SignUpSignIn" Type="Call">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signinandsignupwithpassword1.1">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPassword" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </SubJourney>
    <SubJourney Id="IdentityProviderSelection_LocalAccountDiscovery" Type="Call">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </SubJourney>
  </SubJourneys>
```

`IdentityProviderSelection_SignUpSignIn`, in turn, looks like this, from which, if I understand right, step 2 would be skipped as we're not using a social provider, and steps 3-5 would be skipped due to their conditions:

```
    <SubJourney Id="IdentityProviderSelection_SignUpSignIn" Type="Call">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signinandsignupwithpassword1.1">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email-V3" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninUsernameExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username-V3" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninPhoneExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Phone-Only-V2" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninPhoneEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-PhoneEmail-V3" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isLocalAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="MicrosoftAccountExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MSA-OIDC" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LinkedInExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LinkedIn-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AmazonExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Amazon-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail-Selection" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonNameExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName-Selection" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonPhoneExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonPhone" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ReadAndCreateSsoSession" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-CreateSubject" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ChangePhoneNumber" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneInputPage_ChangePhoneNumber" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPassword" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="WeiboExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Weibo-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="QQExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="QQ-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="WeChatExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="WeChat-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="TwitterExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Twitter-OAUTH1" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GitHubExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GitHub-OAUTH2" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AppleManagedExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Apple-Managed-OIDC" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>passwordExpired</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="LocalAccount_SignUp" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Performs additonal steps for phone/combination based signin -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>passwordExpired</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="AdditionalUserJourneySteps_V2" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>blockUserSignUp</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>passwordExpired</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="AdditionalVerification" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>continueOnPasswordExpiration</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>passwordExpired</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForcePasswordResetUponPasswordExpiration" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ForcePasswordReset-ExpiredPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </SubJourney>
```

Lastly, `SelfAsserted-ForcePasswordReset-ExpiredPassword` is the place which invokes the write:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-ForcePasswordReset-ExpiredPassword">
          <DisplayName>Password Expired</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.expiredpassword</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Please enter a different password</Item>
            <Item Key="TokenLifeTimeInSeconds">3600</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_JwtTokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetResponseMessageForForcedPasswordReset" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="responseMsg" DefaultValue="Your password has expired, please change to a new password." />
          </InputClaims>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="responseMsg" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="eSTS-NonInteractive" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ThrowErrorWhenPassowrdIsSame" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

I did a bunch of experimenting, and crucially, it looks like for whatever reason, step6 in my journey, where `SelfAsserted-ForcePasswordReset-ExpiredPassword` is being invoked, does *not* have `objectId`, even though it seems to be getting set in the first step of the journey. I tried adding it in as an input claim, but that didn't seem to do anything.

For completeness, the code for `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin` is:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="forceChangePasswordNextLogin" PartnerClaimType="passwordProfile.forceChangePasswordNextLogin" DefaultValue="false" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-WriteCommon" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: The technical profiles you've included are incomplete AAD technical profiles, there's a lot of info missing (all the `<Metadata>` contents and the `<IncludeTechnicalProfile>` that makes it hard to guess the impact of changes. I've made a suggestion below, but it might be easier to advise with the actual technical profiles.

Answer (score 0):

If your `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin` technical profile doesn't need to update the name details then it shouldn't reference a technical profile that writes those details.

If your `AAD-WriteCommon` technical profile references `AAD-Common` or something similar then you could try updating `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin` to also reference `AAD-Common` instead of `AAD-WriteCommon`. If you do this you may have to set some additional properties directly on `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin`. See also [the reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#write) for how to write a write AAD technical profile.

Alternatively, if `AAD-WriteCommon` is meant to be a generic base technical profile for writing any user record then you might want to remove the fields from it that are causing a problem and add them to the specific technical profiles that need to write the user's name.

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for the feedback! All of the stuff I've included, with the exception of `CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName`, is "OOTB", so to speak. I got it by exporting the default profiles from Azure AD B2C, by following this guide: https://blog.wojtek.pro/azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-how-to-begin/ , so I'm somewhat reluctant to mess around with it too much. I could certainly change it to `AAD-Common`, I just don't know what consequences that will have. Is there no way to change `CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName` instead? Maybe to make it optional somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to make an InputClaimsTransformation optional like there is with some other elements. Given that link and you saying you exported the policy I'm assuming you created a User Profile user flow and exported that? (that gives me a policy with `AAD-(Read|Write)Common`) You've then created and added the InputClaimsTransformation? It might be that you can move where that claims transformation happens, so you execute it either as a validation step or OutputClaimsTransformation on a self asserted technical profile, or as a standalone orchestration step before calling AAD.

Comment: Can you post your journey and/or the technical profile where `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectIdWithoutStrongAuth-ResetNextLogin` is being called?

Comment: Hi Dave - updated my answer with the full trace, I believe. Apologies for formatting problems - I can't figure out how to easily get the tabs to line up for this.